# Multiply nested array lengths and return a single value

Tags: javascript, arrays

How can i multiply the length of the nested `values` array using this array:

```
const options = [
  {
    name: "Colors",
    values: [{
      label: "Blue"
    },
    {
      label: "Red"
    }]
  },
  {
    name: "Sizes",
    values: [{
      label: "Small"
    },
    {
      label: "Large"
    }]
  }
]
```

My code:

```js
const options = [
  {
    name: "Colors",
    values: [
      {
        label: "Blue"
      },
      {
        label: "Red"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    name: "Sizes",
    values: [
      {
        label: "Small"
      },
      {
        label: "Large"
      }
    ]
  }
];

const multiply = options.reduce((a, b) => a * b.values.length, 0);

console.log(multiply);
```

I've tried with reduce but always return 0. It should return ex. `4`

playground: https://codesandbox.io/s/08jrnr72w

**edit**: thanks everyone for the answers, I missed initial position...

Comment: You are multiplying with an initial value of 0. Any number multiplied by 0 will return 0. Just replace `0` with `1` https://codesandbox.io/s/l9p345r3x7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reduce function expects an initial value. The initial value you provided is 0. If you multiply 0 with anything, you'll get 0.

You should initialize your accumulator with 1. That should fix it.

But you might have to do more, i.e. handle the edge condition. For example, at one point you may get 0 as length for one particular object and in that case, your accumulator will evaluate to 0.

Comment: This is the correct answer, since it also takes care of mentioning that there might be an element with `0` length in the array. Moreover, you may also take care of elements that **do not have** a `values` property.

Comment: thanks for pointing it out, in my case values will always have values, @jayendra-sharan would you mind posting an edge condition? It would be great for reference.

Comment: I have created a fork, you can play around it and let me know if something doesn't work. https://codesandbox.io/s/zx90ww42rl

Please mark as accepted if it resolved your issue.

Answer (score 2):

You need to initialize `Array.prototype.reduce` with 1 for multiplication (multiplying by zero is always going to end up as zero):

```
const multiply = options.reduce((a, b) => a * b.values.length, 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Map them to lengths and then reduce the results.

```js
const options = [
  {
    name: "Colors",
    values: [{
      label: "Blue"
    },
    {
      label: "Red"
    }]
  },
  {
    name: "Sizes",
    values: [{
      label: "Small"
    },
    {
      label: "Large"
    }]
  }
]

const multValues = options.map(opt => opt.values.length).reduce((a,b) => a*b);
console.log(multValues)
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your starting value to `1` as `0` times anything is `0` (thus your accumulator (`a`) will always be `0`):

```js
const options=[{name:"Colors",values:[{label:"Blue"},{label:"Red"}]},{name:"Sizes",values:[{label:"Small"},{label:"Large"}]}];

// change starting value -------------------------------------\/
const multiply = options.reduce((a, b) => a * b.values.length, 1);

console.log(multiply);
```